# Weak derivatives equals zero

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Im just learning sobovel space, I was wondering if the weak derivate holds similar things of the original derivate.

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is a open set, and $u\in W^{1,p}$

if $$Du=0 \ \ a.e$$

implies $u=\mathrm{const}?$

Comment: Yes, if $U$ is connected. No, if not.

Comment: What what is the link between $u$ and $U$ in your question as written ? There seems to be none...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\phi$ is a $C^\infty$ function with compact support then the convolution $u*\phi$ is also smooth, and $D(u*\phi)=(Du)*\phi=0$. So $u*\phi$ is locally constant by the usual calculus argument. Now let $\phi$ be a standard mollifier and let it converge to a delta, so that $u*\phi$ converges to $u$ a.e. (or in $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ if you prefer). So $u$ is locally constant.

Comment: Can you explain better?

Comment: @avati91 I could, but it would be at the very least ten times as long, and I don't have the time (or inclination, to be honest). If there is a specific point you find unclear I might be able to point you in the right direction, however.

Comment: Hi Harald, I feel like it is necessary to add one more intermediate step in this way: $D(u*\phi)=u*(D\phi)=(Du)*\phi=0.$ If we want to directly transfer the differentiation operator to $u$, then it may not work because in that process we will need to use the dominated convergence theorem and the fact that $Du$ is not a classic derivative prevents us from having a bound to do so. If we have the intermediate step, then the last step is valid by the definition of weak derivative(because any translation of test functions remains test function).